# Tumblr posts blurry images

Tags: tumblr, photo, image-gallery, blurry

I'm trying this new theme and posts with photosets show blurry images, posts where I add images into the text appear fine with no resolution damage. The weirdest thing is that while fiddling with the code trying to find a solution, the preview site at the right side of the screen shows the images correctly. What could this be?

Here's a link to the tumblr blog I mention: http://cunhafelipe.tumblr.com/ Notice the variation in quality within the posts.

Can anyone please help out with this? I tried EVERYWHERE and couldn't find anything, it's the only theme I could find that doesn't crop my images but on the other hand it's doing this. Seriously, help out a noob that pretty much reached a dead end. HUGE thanks in advance.

Comment: The default photoset `{Photoset-700}`, can only display images at 500px wide which causes the blurring.